# loop function until meets correct input

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my code to keep looping until the correct input is entered, at present the code will compile and run but if an int is entered that is outside the allowed range it will simply return the error message and end, I am trying to find a way to clear the user input and request input again until a correct value is entered.

I have tried cin.clear and also returns but they seem not to work with functions or I simply do not understand how to implement them

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void get_int_ref(int& n);      

int main() {

    int n = 0; 
    get_int_ref(n); 

    return 0;
} 

void get_int_ref(int& n) {      
     cout<< "Please enter an integer\n"; 
     cin>>n;   
     if( n > 4000 )

        {
            cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n" 

        }

     else if (n < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n"; 

        }
     else
        {
            cout<< n <<"\n";
        }

 }
```

Comment: what is your correct input?

Comment: any int between  0 and 4000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the input as string.
2. Check if it is a correct input.
3. If not, ask the user again.

example implementation:

```
#include <sstream> // for using std::stringstream

void get_int_ref(int& n) {
    // you shouldn't repeat writing the same message
    static const char* message = "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n";

    for(;;) // infinite loop
    {
        cout<< "Please enter an integer\n";
        std::string inp;
        if( !(cin>>inp) ) // failed to read a string
        {
            cout << "Input error\n";
            n = -1;
            break; // exit from the loop
        }
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << inp;
        if( !(ss >> n) ) // what is read is not an integer
        {
            cout << message;
        }
        else if( n >= 4000 ) // correct condition according to the message
        {
            cout << message;
        }
        else if (n <= 0) // correct condition according to the message
        {
            cout << message;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << n << "\n";
            break; // exit from the loop
        }
    }
}
```

or the checking part can be more simple:

```
#include <sstream> // for using std::stringstream

void get_int_ref(int& n) {
    for(;;) // infinite loop
    {
        cout<< "Please enter an integer\n";
        std::string inp;
        if( !(cin>>inp )) // failed to read a string
        {
            cout << "Input error\n";
            n = -1;
            break; // exit from the loop
        }
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << inp;
        if( !(ss >> n) || n >= 4000 || n <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << n << "\n";
            break; // exit from the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea of using `std::stringstream`, you can easily check input data.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a loop, for example, like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n"
        cin >> n;
        if (is_entered_value_valid(n)) break;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool is_entered_value_valid(const int& n)
{
    bool valid = true;
    if( (n > 4000) || (n < 0) )
    {
        cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n"
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

As fairly @MikeCAT noted in the commentary block users might not always enter correct input. They might enter characters as well, like `FooBar`. Then this program gets existed with a error. You might need to add more complex input procedures with verification of the user's input. Let me know, If you need one.

Comment: No I can expect only int and nothing else so this is fine

Comment: @MikeCAT, thank you for you note, I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a loop and `break` when detecting a correct input?

```
 while( true )
 {
     cout<< "Please enter an integer\n"; 
     cin>>n;   
     if( ( n > 4000 ) || ( n < 0 ) )
     {
            cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n";
     }
     else
     {
            cout<< n <<"\n";
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Only need int nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Separate the function into two functions:

1. Get input.
2. Check whether the input is valid.

Call them in a `while` loop from `main`.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <limits>  // Needed for numeric_limits

 using namespace std;

 bool is_input_valid(int n);
 int get_input();      

 int main() {

     int n = get_input(); 
     while ( !(is_input_valid(n)) )
     {
        n = get_input();
     }

     return 0;
 } 

 int get_input() {      
    int n;
    cout << "Error enter a number between 0 and 4000: \n" 
    cin >> n; 

    // If there was a problem reading the input, clear the input stream
    // and try again.
    if ( !cin )
    {
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       return get_input();
    }

    return n;
 }

 bool is_input_valid(int n)
 {
    return ( n >= 0 && n <= 4000 );
 }
```

Comment: Only need int nothing else

Comment: @Ausghostdogl, elaborate please.

Comment: How @MikeCAT said about boo, well the input will only ever be an int, never a double or string or anything else only ints

Comment: @Ausghostdog, I see. However, it is always good to make your program more robust with a little extra effort.

Comment: @Ausghostdog How do you grantee that? By deleting your program and letting no one execute the program?

Comment: @MikeCAT I grantee that given the assessment questions states "Question 3 (3%)
Implement get_int_ref():
/**
Get integer input from keyboard.Assumption: the input is always an 
integer.Prompt: “Please enter an integer: “
param n:integer input from keyboard.
*/
void get_int_ref(int&n);"

Comment: @Ausghostdog I didn't know that because you didn't disclose that.

Comment: @MikeCAT Correct, I am sorry about that and will remember to declare that next time, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively.

```
void get_int_ref(int& n)
{
    cout<< "Please enter an integer\n";
    cin>>n;
    if( n > 4000 )
    {
        cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n";
        get_int_ref(n);
    }

    else if (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error enter a number n: 0 < n < 4000: \n";
        get_int_ref(n);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< n <<"\n";
        return;
    }

}
```